# When I kill my app through multitask swipe, it won't lock onto location anymore until I reinstall it

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a navigation app that relies on the Google Maps API. When I first load the app from Android Studio onto my phone it asks me if I'd like to allow location access for the app. So the user can hit allow (if they're running 6.0+) and the location is displayed in a layout.

The problem arises when I kill the process by swiping it on multitasking. When I go to open the app again, my phone doesn't display the location pin in the status bar and nothing is read from the view.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;
private Button button;
private TextView textView;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_request);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_coordinates);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            textView.setText("Coordinates:\n " + location.getLatitude() + "\n " + location.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           requestPermissions(new String[] {
                   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                   Manifest.permission.INTERNET
           }, 10 );
            return;
        }
    }else{
         configureButton();
    }
}

private void configureButton() {
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 2000, 10, locationListener);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                configureButton();
            }
            return;
    }
}
```

}

I have tried moving the line of code below around within the project but I quickly realized I have no idea what I am doing.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 2000, 10, locationListener);
```

Have you ever run into this problem? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Instead of swiping the app away from the multitask view, can you "force stop" the app and when you re-open it, does it show the proper location then?

Comment: @Blaasd, yes that produces the same problem.

Comment: What do you have in your onConnectionFailed, onConnectionSuspended, onConnected, onStart and onResume methods?